# Get control flow information with JaCoCo

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, control-flow, jacoco-maven-plugin

Looking for a way to retrieve control flow information, such as local variables and their values and which instructions/branches were executed for the tested methods using JaCoCo (0.8.11). I am running it on IntelliJ with maven.

The only clue I found was specifying jacoco agent .jar file when executing tests, but even then it is unclear how exactly to use it. So I am looking for clarifications or any alternative solutions. Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2023/10/2023-10-26-maven-jacoco-configuration/ That sounds like you need a debugger. That gives you information during the steps about values of variables etc. But JaCoCo will not give you such information...